# Docusign Template not changing

Tags: docusignapi

My DocuSign template is not changing for new envelopes even though I changed the javascript reference to the template in my custom button in Salesforce. It continues to present the old template in the envelope, even after I deleted the old template from my DocuSign account??

Answer (score 0):

Cancel that - figured it out - rookie error. Wrong button editted